# Angular - ngStyle return [object Object] when function that returns a es6 string is passed

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, ng-style

The template component is this:

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
    <li class="list-group-item no-border" *ngFor="let color of colorList">
        <button class="btn btn-link" (click)="setColor(color.hex)">{{ color.name }}</button>
    </li>
</ul>

{{ selectedColor }}
<div class="colorBlock" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': selectedColor }"></div>
```

Basically my component has to change the background-color on the event `(click)` of the button:

```
export class BlockColorChangerComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Change the color of the block.';
  selectedColor: any = this.setColor();
  colorList = [
    {name: 'Red',  hex: '255,0,0'},
    {name: 'Blue',    hex: '0,0,255'},
    {name: 'Green',  hex: '0,255,0'},
    {name: 'Yellow', hex: '255,255,0'},
    {name: 'Pink',   hex: '255,200,255'},
    {name: 'Random'}
  ];

  randomColor() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  }

  setColor(hex?) {
    this.selectedColor = `rgb('${hex === undefined ? this.randomColor() : hex}')`;
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setColor();
  }
}
```

On the render, the `<div>` shows:

```
<div _ngcontent-c1="" class="colorBlock" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"></div>
```

While `{{ selectedColor }}` updates the string correctly.
I'm still trying to figure out what ES6 new type of string can do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need little modification in your `setColor(hex?)` function. just remove single quotations. Ex:

```
this.selectedColor = `rgb(${hex === undefined ? this.randomColor() : hex})`;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
  <div class="colorBlock" [style.background]="selectedColor"></div>
```

Comment: doesn't work sadly. it gives me a warning `WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value rgb('5,216,206')`

Comment: you can try like this 
this.selectedColor = this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`rgb('5,216,206')`); let me know if it is works or now :)

Comment: @NikitaFuchs Ohh that's great, Welcome :)